# Libreoffice Writer: Text in portrait mode and tables in landscape mode

Tags: libreoffice, writer

The paper I am writing currently, has certain tables which do not fit in the portrait mode.

Therefore, while the requirement of the paper is the portrait mode, the tables need to be in the landscape mode. What is that way, by which I can either rotate the tables, or insert a section break and change the layout of the section to support the landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

I believe section breaks are just Insert->Manual Break->Page Break, and make sure the "next style" selected for after the break is set for landscape/default appropriately.